# Using full or relative path in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, relative-path

I have created a batch script that requires the location of 2 files to be passed into it. I would like it to work regardless of whether the user gives the full file path or relative file path of the files to be read in.

I've tried the following

```
set Var1=%~dp0%1
set Var2=%~dp0%2
```

which only works if relative file path is given. Without `%~dp0`obviously only works if full path is given.

Is there a way for either the full or relative path to be given and for my batch file to work.

Thanks

Comment: A full path begins with a single alphabet character followed by a colon and then a backslash, e.g. ```X:\```. If the input parameters do not begin with those three characters, it must be a part path, or relative path. If the input paramether begins with one or two periods, followed by a backslash, e.g. ```..\```, then it must be a relative path. Of course neither of those two facts matter, if it is not clear whether those paths are supposed to be relative to a specific directory location. Your code suggests that the paths must be at least relative to the batch files' parent directory.

Comment: In order therefore to achieve your goal, it should initiallly be obvious to the end user whether they should be passing their input paramethers as full absolute paths, or relative to a specific location. Once you've done that, you would be best advised to validate the input by checking for the characters up to the first backslash, this would ensure that you know which of the three has been provided. Without supplying sufficient code and background information for us to undertand the exact task, it would be guess work for us to provide anything more robust, as a solution to your specific issue.